# Rails app ArgumentError in RelationshipsController#create

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble between my relationships controller and shops model.  I'm using relationships to create a friending-like association between shops and users.  When trying to add a user as a shop, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError in RelationshipsController#create
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

on the first line in `add(user)` in the shop model:

**shop.rb**

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :users, through: :relationships
.
.
.
def add(user)
  relationships.create(user_id: other_user.id)
end
.
.
end
```

This command is triggered by "create" in the relationships controller:

**relationships_controller.rb**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_shop

  def create
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_shop.add.relationship(user)
    redirect_to user
  end

  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:user_id])
    current_shop.remove.relationship(user)
    redirect_to user
  end
end
```

after clicking this add button:

```
<%= form_for(current_shop.relationships.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

For some reason the argument (user) isn't being carried to the `add(user)` method.  How can I make this work?  (I understand there are several errors in my syntax, this is a working version.  Looking for help on this specific error, will deal with others after I get rid of this error).

**Relationship Model**

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :shop
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :shop_id, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is raised because you called `add` without any arguments:

```
current_shop.add.relationship(user)
```

Since you have implemented `add` taking one argument, you should pass it

```
def create
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  current_shop.add(user)  
  redirect_to user
end
```